# Как удалить дубликаты строк по условию?

Tags: python, pandas

Есть большой `df` с разными колонками. Нужно найти дубликаты строк. Поиск должен идти только по определенным колонкам и удалить только те, где в колонке `type = 0`.

Каким образом можно объединить `drop_duplicates` и условие на `type`?

Как пример:

```
id  name   type  date
1   anna   1     2021-01-01
1   anna   0     2005-17-11
1   anna   1     2099-01-05
```

Из такого примера нужно удалить только вторую строчку.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Воспользуйтесь комбинацией методов [DataFrame.duplicated()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) и [DataFrame.query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
mask = df.duplicated(subset=["id", "name"]) & df.query("type == 0")
res = df.loc[~mask]
```

Answer (score 1):

вот еще рабочий вариант:

```
del_dupl = df[~((df.duplicated(['id','name']))&(df.type==0))]
```

Comment: большое спасибо за помощь, этот вариант у меня заработал. Но тут оказалось другая штука - а каким образом можно в запросе указать, чтобы на определенные колонки он не смотрел? Т.е. у меня сейчас, после выполнения такого запроса остаются дубли, изза того, что в столбце с датой стоят разные значения